# Problema con rutina de jQuery para mostrar contenido con botones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Tengo dos botones en donde debería apretar y que me muestre tres botones más que están ocultos más una de la información de cada botón.

Mi idea es que cuando abra la sección me muestre el contenido del primer botón (Servicio al Vecino), y que muestre el contenido de emprender.

Inicialmente puedo tener oculto el contenido y a medida que se presionan botones, los activo pero lo que me pidieron fue que cuando entras a la sección esté activo el botón "Servicio para Vecinos" y que muestre el contenido del botón "Emprender" solamente. Hasta donde puede hacer era que mostraba todo el contenido de todos los botones. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

El armado del HTML:

```js
$(".button2").click(function() {

  $(".button2").removeClass("activo");
  $(this).addClass("activo");

  $(".descripcion .art").hide();

  var indice_seccion = $(".button2").index($(this));
  $(".descripcion .art").eq(indice_seccion).show();

  return false;
});

$(".descripcion .art").show();

$(".button").click(function() {

  $(".button").removeClass("activo");
  $(this).addClass("activo");

  $(".btn .menu2").hide();

  var indice_seccion = $(".button").index($(this));
  $(".btn .menu2").eq(indice_seccion).show();

  return false;
});
$(".btn .menu2").eq(0).show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" title="" class="button">Servicio para Vecinos</a>
<a href="" title="" class="button">Servicio para Empresas</a>


<section class="btn">
  <article class="menu2">

    <a href="" title="" class="button2">EMPRENDER</a>
    <a href="" title="" class="button2">AHORRO</a>
    <a href="" title="" class="button2">EMPLEO</a>

    <section class="descripcion">
      <article id="ver" class="art muestra">
        aqui va el texto
      </article>
    </section>
    <section class="descripcion">
      <article id="ver" class="art muestra">
        aqui va el 2 texto
      </article>
    </section>
    <section class="descripcion">
      <article id="ver" class="art muestra">
        aqui va 3 texto
      </article>
    </section>
  </article>

</section>
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: mi idea es que cuando abra la sección me muestre el contenido del primero botón (servicio al vecino), y que muestre el contenido de emprender.

Comment: Inicialmente puedes tener oculto el contenido y a medida que presionas botones los activas

Comment: claro! pero lo que me pidieron fue que cuando entras a la sección este activo el boton Servicio para Vecinos y que muestre el contenido del botón Emprender solamente. Hasta donde puede hacer era que mostraba todo el contenido de todos los botones.

Comment: Si te entiendo, ocultas el segundo section inicialmente y luego lo demas

Comment: y como seria???

Comment: bueno los section deverian tener id diferente para poder trabajarlos y al section 2 le das un estilo display: none;